# How can I use javascript postMessage between iframe to iframe with different domains?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having problems using postMessage between iframe to iframe with different domains because of cross-domain issue. My code works with parent to child and vice versa. But I can't pass a message from one iframe to another.

Is there any solution for that?

Edited: 
These are the codes -
iframe1 - I added it on jsbin.com (which will send a message on iframe1 and vice versa)

```
var button = document.getElementById('b2');
  var input = document.getElementById('m2');
  var origin = origin || window.location.origin;
  button.onclick = function() {
      window.parent.postMessage(input.value, "*");
  };

  var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
  var eventer = window[eventMethod];
  var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

  eventer(messageEvent, function(e) {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = e.data;
  },false);
```

---

iframe2

```
var submit = document.getElementById('b2');
var input = document.getElementById('m2');
submit.onclick = function() {
 var origin = origin || window.location.origin;     
 window.parent.postMessage(input.value, origin);
};

var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

eventer(messageEvent, function(e) {
 output = e.data;
 document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = e.data;
},false);
```

I just did the same thing with receiving and sending the message. But I always got this error in the console. 
 Unable to post message to http://jsbin.com. Recipient has origin http://mypersonaldomain.com

I've already tried two different domains but within parent to child and child to parent, but can't do iframe to iframe with different domains, is it possible that these two iframes can communicate without adding some codes in their parent html?

Thanks for those comments!

Comment: Yeah, `postMessage` allows for that. It's up to the receiver whether they want to read the message or not. The sender can also filter who it goes to. Read about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage

Comment: If you want to pass a message from one `iframe` to a different `iframe` on a page then I'd expect you'd have to write some code in the parent page to pass those messages on.

Comment: I always got this error in the console:
Blocked a frame with origin "http://jsbin.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://http://mypersonaldomain.com" or
Unable to post message to http://jsbin.com. Recipient has origin http://mypersonaldomain.com

Comment: Try looking at this example http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage there is an Example on that page. Enter a message and submit. It will post to an iFrame. See if it can help solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I solved the issue by specifying the frame object of the parent window:
 button.onclick = function(e) {        
    window.top.frames[1].postMessage(input.value, "*");
  };